# How can I remove a drop-down list item that is dynamically populated by a link in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have been stuck on how to remove a drop-down item that is populated via a dynamic link in the DB. I have tried things like `pageoption.OptionValue.Remove(pageoption.OptionValue.FindByValue("Coordination of Care Participants"));` but I receive an error message. I also used "Find", "FindAll", etc. I also tried to remove it using Jquery.

Here is the front-end/View; obviously, I removed several options, as this is a sample of the parts I am working with:

```
 <select id="inpatientGridActionSelect" class="form-control action-select" data-roomNum="@r.ID" onchange="openAlertsD('@p.ClientId', '@p.ClientName.Replace("'", "")','@p.AdmitId', this)">
                                        

    @if (Model.PageActionOptions != null)
        {
           foreach (var pageoption in Model.PageActionOptions)
          {
           <option value="@pageoption.OptionValue" data-linkPath="@pageoption.LinkPath">@pageoption.OptionName</option>
                                                
            }
                }
```

Any tips are much appreciated, Thank you.